# .exe timeout when called by IIS mvc application

Tags: powershell, iis, model-view-controller, process, console

I am trying to create a site collection and apply theme to it using c# and PowerShell.
I have written code on console application which invokes PowerShell script.
When I click the console.exe file it creates the SharePoint site as required but when I hit the same console.exe from IIS hosted MVC application it does not applies theme but site collection gets created.
Any error because I am not able to locate them.
Any help is appreciated..
I have tried extending timeout..
and I am not sure if this is the error